# Cannot read Parcelable from Intent in onActivityReenter

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, parcelable, onactivityresult

I want to return my address model as result in `Intent`. If I try get my address model in `onAcivityResult` methods all works fine, but in `onActivityReenter` I got this `Exception`:

```
Class not found when unmarshalling: ua.com.uklontaxi.models.UIAddress
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ua.com.myapp.models.UIAddress
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2383)
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2337)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2243)
    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2592)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:786)
```

There are not such errors in another places (for example `onActivityResult` in the same `Activity`)

**How to fix it?**

P.S. I put my model to `Bundle` and then I put this bundle to `Intent`. I tried put address to `Intent` without `Bundle`-wrapping. It doens't help me.

Comment: post more of the stacktrace please. Where is the error occuring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helps me:

```
override fun onActivityReenter(resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
   super.onActivityReenter(resultCode, data)

   data?.setExtrasClassLoader(this.classLoader) // this is context!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still wondering why this issue persists **only** for API versions **below** Oreo (8), it has to do with a fix that was provided for API 8+. You can find the official fix [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/88f6bc82f9f9305c81fa77ceb571c053c51f4d29%5E%21/#F0) or you can check the below code (taken from the official repo):

```
Intent intent = mEnterActivityOptions.getResultData();
   if (intent != null) {
        intent.setExtrasClassLoader(activity.getClassLoader());
    }
activity.onActivityReenter(result, intent);
```

It essentially, adds manually the `ClassLoader` to the `Intent`, before calling the `Activity`'s `onActivityReenter(...);`